# Google Charts - Format vAxis point instead of comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, formatting, google-visualization

How to format vAxis in google charts that would display vertical scale with points instead of commas.
Example(now): 100,000
Example(then): 100.000

I know that the trick is with 'format' function, but I can't get it to work like i want.

I am trying to format it like with this:

```
vAxis: {minValue:0, format:'##.##'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `format` option does not meet your needs,
you can use the `ticks` option to provide custom labels

using object notation, you can provide both the...

`v:` - value for the axis
`f:` - formatted value for the label

```
{v: 100000, f: '100.000'}
```

see following working snippet

the `NumberFormat` class is used, *in an attempt* to create the format
(not sure exactly what is needed)

data table method `getColumnRange` is used to find the range of the y-axis

a loop builds each tick for the axis labels...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 500000],
    [1, 500000],
    [2, 200000],
    [3, 700000],
    [4, 400000]
  ]);

  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    groupingSymbol: '.',
    fractionDigits: 0
  });

  var ticksY = [];
  var yRange = data.getColumnRange(1);
  for (var i = 0; i <= yRange.max; i=i+100000) {
    ticksY.push({
      v: i,
      f: formatNumber.formatValue(i)
    });
  }

  var options = {
    vAxis: {
      ticks: ticksY
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div')
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
vAxis.format:{format:'##.##'}
```

Comment: Still the same :/

Comment: this is the reference of google charts may help you:
[link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options)

Comment: The 'vAxis.format' notation is not what you should actually use (unless you are assigning to an object, e.g. options.vAxis.format = '...').  It is intended as an abbreviation for the nested structure: vAxis: { format: '...' }.